# Looking for a CMS including Wiki, possibility to comment on individual paragraphs of the wiki and making these comments visible on the same page

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, comments, wiki, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking for a specific CMS including Wiki, possibility to comment
on individual paragraphs of the wiki and making these comments visible
on the same page. The CMS should have a user system that allows to
rate users on the quality of their comments. Ideally, the System
should allow for different user roles/permissions based on their
experience.  I looked at the site rapgenius.com and would like to use
it for a similar project in which people can contribute texts, work on
developing these texts and comment on text passages.

Sorry, I am not a software engineer or webmaster but I thought this
might be a good forum for my query.

Answer (score 0):

[CommentPress](http://www.futureofthebook.org/commentpress/) is a theme/plugin for WordPress that does this sort of thing. It's main intent is for academic use, but no reason you couldn't appropriate it. It doesn't have any built-in rating functionality that I'm aware of, but there are enough standalone plugins for that you could bolt on.